# BINARY_DOUBLE and support for double.PositiveInfinity

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using latest ODAC with Entity Framework 4.1. I use the BINARY_DOUBLE type which gets mapped to a .NET double. I store the results of double arithmetic which mostly works fine, however if the result is Infinity (double.PositiveInfinity) then Oracle throws this error when I SaveChanges:

> ORA-01426: numeric overflow

Since Oracle BINARY_DOUBLE supposedly does support +Inf, -Inf and NaN (documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13085_01/doc/timesten.1121/e13070/types.htm), why does this not work correctly through EF? (NaN does work actually, its just the infinities that have this problem).

Is there a way to "fix-up" the result before I save it such that it gets stored as +Inf in Oracle?

Comment: first thing to check: does +inf/-inf work via the Oracle ADO.NET provider
? If it doesn't work via ADO.NET, then EF doesn't stand a chance.

Comment: You linked to the TimeTen documentation, which is not quite the same thing as regular Oracle.  Perhaps the literal [BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#r5c1-t54) can help?

Comment: It works fine with ADO.NET.  Also tried double.MaxValue (in EF) and gives numeric overflow too.  Is it possible to access BINARY_DOUBLE_INFINITY from within my C# code?